# Rescue Phoenix.MissingParamError and return json for user

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following action in one of controllers in my Phoenix app:

```
      plug :scrub_params, "account"
      plug :scrub_params, "studio"

      def create(conn, %{"account" => account_params, "studio" => studio_params}) do
      end
```

When somebody do not send proper params app is returning `Phoenix.MissingParamError` error. How can I rescue it and return nice message to user in json?

Comment: In Phoenix 1.3 you can use action_fallback and move the error handling to one different error controller.

Comment: This `Phoenix.MissingParamError` is being thrown my `scrub_params` right? In that case adding another clause (like the top answer right now) won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could create another function head to handle that case. Something like this, maybe

```
def create(conn, %{"account" => account_params, "studio" => studio_params}) do 
  # handle request
end

def create(conn, params) do 
  # handle missing param
end
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but then I need to repeat this for another actions which is bad...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the Plug.ErrorHandler. something like this.

```
defmodule AppRouter do 
  use Plug.Router 
  use Plug.ErrorHandler 

  ... 

  def handle_errors(conn, %{kind: _kind, reason: _reason, stack: _stack}) do 
    send_resp(conn, conn.status, "Something went wrong") 
  end 
end
```